# Submitting multiple forms in a row in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a browser extension which will allow me to click a button and then send me through a checkout process. I am able to submit my first form and add my item to cart, but when I attempt to submit the second form nothing happens. I think the issue here comes down to the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkout);` being triggered again after the first form is submitted. I have searched through a ton of stuff on stack and google and haven't seen much about this. Basically, how can I handle submitting a form and then grabbing a form from the following page and submitting that as well in javascript? Here is the code for my main javascript file.

```js
function checkout() {
    this.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.calle, false);
    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "submitForm.js"
        });
    });
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: "goToCheckOut.js"
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', checkout);
```

and here is the method submitForm.js

```js
var i = document.createElement('input');
i.name = 'id';
var xpath = "//*[local-name()='li' and text()='10.5']";
var nsResolver = document.createNSResolver(document.ownerDocument == null ? document.documentElement : document.ownerDocument.documentElement);
var liElements = document.evaluate(xpath, document, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var ele = liElements.iterateNext();
var id = ele.getAttribute("data-value");
i.value = id;
document.getElementById("AddToCartForm").appendChild(i);
document.getElementById("AddToCartForm").submit();
```

Currently this is all I am trying to do in goToCheckOut.js and it is not running unless I do not click the button

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].